# Direct a HTML page to login page

Tags: javascript, html

I have created two HTML pages, one is called `login.html` and the other -- `resume.html`.

What I want to do is, that no matter which page I open, I'll be always redirected to login page. If I open the `login.html`, it will be opened up and I fill in the `username` and `password` fields, then the `resume.html` opens.

My problem is, that I don't know the code, which I should add, to be redirected to `login.html`, when I open the `resume.html`.

The code of the login page is :

```
  <html>
  <head>

   <title>
   Login page
   </title>
   </head>

  <body>
   <h1 style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;text-align:center;font-size:50pt;color:#ff00ba;">
   You need to login :) </h1>     

   <form style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms; text-align:center">
   Username<br>
  <input type="text" name="userid"/><br>
   Password<br>
  <input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
  <br><br>
  <input style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;" type="button" onclick="check(form)" value="Login">
  <input style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;" type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
  </form>


  <script language="javascript">
  function check(form)
  {

   if(form.userid.value == "pwan9047" && form.pswrd.value == "Wang1984")
  {
    window.open('resume.html')
  }
  else
  {
  alert("Error Password or Username")
  }
  }
  </script>
   </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If JavaScript is broken or disabled, any JS-based solution won't work. This should be handled server-side.

Comment: You want to check if the user is logged in, if not, redirect to login.html

Comment: well, I do not really have a server side, I can use JS to do that but just do not know which syntax I should use to achieve this function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register in the `localStorage` whether the user is logged in, when the button is clicked.

So change this:

```
if(form.userid.value == "pwan9047" && form.pswrd.value == "Wang1984")
  {
    window.open('resume.html')
  }
```

to this:

```
if(form.userid.value == "pwan9047" && form.pswrd.value == "Wang1984")
  {
    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', true);location.href='/resume.html';
  }
```

Add the log out button to your html in the `login.html`, so as to be able to log out, of course:

```
<input style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;" type="button" value="Log out" onclick="localStorage.removeItem('isLoggedIn');location.href='/login.html'"/>
```

And add this code in the `<head>` of your `/resume.html` and any other page which you want to be accessible only if you are logged in:

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn')==null){
       location.href="/login.html";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that while this is correct given the requirements, this will also cause you to never really navigate to resume.html as it will immediately send you back. You'll need some sort of condition like a session variable to decide if you should be redirected or not.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, so which html file I should be use to fill in your code? You mean I need to add this to the <head> of resume.html file? Or both?

Comment: The question states that after log in, you are directed to the `resume.html` page.  Won't this answer break that requirement?

Comment: Hi Ben, yes, resume page will be opened up if the login is successful. What I mean is if I just directly open the resume page, is there a way that I can make it go to login page? Because I do not want the resume page opened without login.

Comment: That bit of code simply says when the page is loaded send me to "login.html" instead. So you would want to put that in "resume.html" and any other pages that you would want the user to be logged in to see.

Comment: Hi, I tried the code, but it is not working, it still opens the resume page

Comment: I added to the resume html, but nothing happened

Comment: Hey Nicael, it actually worked through my editor (I am using Brackets), but when I actually open the html files themselves, it shows the webpage could not be found, the both inks in my browser are "file:///C:/username.html" and "file:///C:/resume.html", it seems it could not find the right location of the file, but why it is working under the editor then?